# Wrap text in equations?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-breaking

I'm writing a web application which generates LaTeX code to visualize an equation. There's one significant roadblock I'm running into: Sometimes, a part of the produced equation has a large number of terms added together, which results in a very long line, such as this:
[image: too wide]
...there could conceivably be 15 or 20 terms in that numerator, which would end up requiring horizontal scrolling, which I want to avoid. I'd prefer it looked a bit more like this:

[image: much better]

...I can accomplish the above manually by looking at the original output and deciding where to put the linebreaks, and then using nested `\atop` commands to stack the lines (poor spacing between lines notwithstanding). Here's the code for that:

```
\[
\left(
    \left(
        \frac{
            \left(
                {
                    \texttt{5dc} \: + \: 
                    \texttt{5dc} \: + \: 
                    \texttt{5dc} \: + \: 
                    \texttt{5dc} \:
                \atop
                    + \:
                    \min
                    \left(
                        \left(
                            \texttt{5dc} \: \times \: 
                            \texttt{10}
                        \right), 
                        \texttt{1}
                    \right) \: + \: 
                        \left\langle
                            \:
                            \texttt{5dc} >
                            \texttt{0} \:
                        \right\rangle
                    \: 
                } 
                \atop + \: 
                \min\left(
                    \left(
                        \texttt{5dc} \: \times \: 
                        \texttt{10}
                    \right), 
                    \texttt{1}
                \right)
                \: + \: 
                \left\langle
                    \:
                    \texttt{5dcx}>
                    \texttt{0}\:
                \right\rangle
            \right)
        }{
            \left(
                \texttt{8} \: + \: 
                \texttt{5dc} \: + \: 
                \texttt{5dc} 
            \right)
        }
    \right)
    \: \times \: 
    \left(
        \texttt{1} \: - \: 
        \texttt{5dc}
    \right)
\right)
\]
```

But what would really be infinitely better would be the ability to use something akin to normal text automatic line-breaking.

Is there any way to do this?

**Note**: This needs to involve a maximum width, not a fixed width; i.e., if the numerator only has one short term in it, for example, the fraction should be only as wide as necessary.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. MathJax is off-topic here.

Comment: As Johannes mentions as mathjax is just a javascript library capable of rendering a subset of the latex syntax it does not use latex underneath, so off topic here.

Comment: @daleif will remove the mathjax-related bits. The core question is definitely not off-topic.

Comment: @siracusa done.

Comment: Weird -- there was an answer, which didn't quite fully solve the problem but got close and was very helpful, but it's now been deleted. Could that have happened when it was briefly closed as off-topic?

Comment: @DanM No, the author of that answer deleted the answer after asking you.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's a shame, it was a very useful answer.